# Removing nested promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, promise

I'm new to promises and writing network code using requests and promises in NodeJS.

I would like to remove these nested promises and chain them instead, but I'm not sure how I'd go about it/whether it is the right way to go.

```
exports.viewFile = function(req, res) {
var fileId = req.params.id;
boxContentRequest('files/' + fileId + '/content', req.user.box.accessToken)
    .then(function(response) {
        boxViewerRequest('documents', {url: response.request.href}, 'POST')
            .then(function(response) {
                boxViewerRequest('sessions', {document_id: response.body.id}, 'POST')
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
            });
    });
};
```

This is the request code:

```
var baseContentURL = 'https://api.box.com/2.0/';
var baseViewerURL = 'https://view-api.box.com/1/';

function boxContentRequest(url, accessToken) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var options = {
                url: baseContentURL + url,
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
                }
            };
      request(options, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
          err = new Error("Unexpected status code: " + res.statusCode);
          err.res = res;
          return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(res);
      });
    });
}

function boxViewerRequest(url, body, method) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var options = {
                method: method,
                url: baseViewerURL + url,
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Token ' + config.box.viewerApiKey
                },
                json: body
            };
      request(options, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        } else if (res.statusCode !== 200 && res.statusCode !== 201 && res.statusCode !== 202) {
          err = new Error("Unexpected status code: " + res.statusCode);
          err.res = res;
          return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(res, body);
      });
    });
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You might be interested in [Request-Promise](https://github.com/tyabonil/request-promise). With this lib you save some code to wrap request into a promise.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From every `then` callback, you will need to *return* the new promise:

```
exports.viewFile = function(req, res) {
    var fileId = req.params.id;
    boxContentRequest('files/' + fileId + '/content', req.user.box.accessToken)
      .then(function(response) {
          return boxViewerRequest('documents', {url: response.request.href}, 'POST');
      })
      .then(function(response) {
          return boxViewerRequest('sessions', {document_id: response.body.id}, 'POST');
      })
      .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
      });
};
```

The promise that is returned by the `.then()` call will then resolve with the value from the "inner" promise, so that you easily can chain them.

Generic pattern:

```
somePromise.then(function(r1) {
    return nextPromise.then(function(r2) {
        return anyValue;
    });
}) // resolves with anyValue

     ||
    \||/
     \/

somePromise.then(function(r1) {
    return nextPromise;
}).then(function(r2) {
    return anyValue;
}) // resolves with anyValue as well
```

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.prototype.then` is designed to return another promise, so that you can chain them.

The handler function passed to `.then()` can return a *normal value*, like a number or string or object, and this value will get passed on to the next handler of `.then()`.

One option is to have `boxViewerRequestSync` be a synchronous function that returns a `response` object:

```
boxContentRequest('files/' + fileId + '/content', req.user.box.accessToken)
    .then(function(response) {
        return boxViewerRequestSync('documents', {url: response.request.href}, 'POST')
    })
    .then(function(response) { // this `response` is returned by `boxViewerRequestSync`
        return boxViewerRequestSync('sessions', {document_id: response.body.id}, 'POST')
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
```

But of course your `boxViewerRequest` is asynchronous and returns a promise instead. In that case, **the handler function passed to `.then()` could also return a [completely unrelated `Promise`](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining#returning-promises)**. This new promise is executed synchronously, and once it is resolved/rejected, its result is passed on to the next handler.

```
boxContentRequest('files/' + fileId + '/content', req.user.box.accessToken)
    .then(function(response) {
        return boxViewerRequest('documents', {url: response.request.href}, 'POST')
    })
    .then(function(response) { // this `response` is the result of resolving the promise returned by `boxViewerRequest`
        return boxViewerRequest('sessions', {document_id: response.body.id}, 'POST')
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
```

Keeping track of all the promises is confusing, but the bottom line is this: `Promise.prototype.then` will *always* return a Promise object, but the handler function *passed* to `Promise.prototype.then` can return anything, even undefined, or even another Promise. Then that value, or the value of the resolved Promise, is passed to the next handler function.