# jQuery promises and dependent AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I'd like to know how to make dependent AJAX calls using promises/deferred from jQuery. Right now I have something like this:

```
$.when($.ajax('https://somedomain.com/getuserinfo/results.jsonp', {
  dataType      : 'jsonp',
  jsonp         : true,
  jsonpCallback : 'userCallback'
}))
.then(function (data) {
  return $.when($.getJSON('http://www.otherdomain.com/user/' + data.userId), $.getJSON('http://www.anotherdomain/user').then(function (json1, json2) {
    return {
      json1  : json1,
      json2  : json2
    };
  });
});
```

It's working for me as expected, but I don't know whether it is a correct way of doing this. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve that?

Comment: You should move this to Code Review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, my question is whether is that a correct way of doing such things?

Comment: You haven't explained why exactly you want to achieve, so we cannot really provide a better way for whatever it is you want to do. You can use `$.ajax(...).then(...)` intead of `$.when($.ajax(...)).then(...)`, but that's all there is to say now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code already seems to work "*correct*", though there are a few things to improve:

> ```
> $.when($.ajax(…))
> ```

You don't need `$.when` here,  `$.ajax` already does return a promise.

> ```
> $.when($.getJSON(…), $.getJSON(…).then(…)
> ```

You're missing a closing parenthesis somewhere here - probably before the `.then`. Assuming that:

> ```
> ….then(function(…){ return ….then(function(…){…}); })
> ```

Since promises are monadic, you can [unnest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572) these callbacks to

```
…
.then(function(…){ return …; })
.then(function(…){…})
```

to avoid the pyramid of doom.

---

jQuery-specific:

> ```
> $.when(…).then(function (json1, json2) {
>   return {
>     json1: json1,
>     json2: json2
>   };
> });
> ```

The arguments to the callback after a `$.when` are not the plain results, but the [`arguments` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) of each `getJSON` deferred resolution. You probably only want the JSON, which is on the first index:

```
$.when(…).then(function (json1, json2) {
  return {
    json1: json1[0],
    json2: json2[0]
  };
});
```

Comment: Well, thanks. But it's not the answer to my question. My question is how to make dependent AJAX calls. I mean I get user details from the first source (in $.when) and according to the data I got from it I'm making two AJAX calls simultaneously to two different sources and sending user details from the first source as params for another AJAX calls.

Comment: That's what I answered in the first sentence: It's done just like you did it!

Comment: Thanks, I just thought it might be incorrect in some way.