# Is there any pattern to orchestrate function calls besides Promises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I'm trying to run away from pyramid of doom. Imagine the following function call series:

```
$.wait(1000).done(function() {
    //Do something

    $.wait(5000).done(function(){
        //Do something else

        $.wait(2200).done(function(){
            //Do something else
        });
    });
});
```

Where the $.wait function is defined as:

```
$.wait = function (duration) {
    return $.Deferred(function (dfd) {
        setTimeout(dfd.resolve, duration);
    });
};
```

The question is that how can I refactor the above code so that it becomes readable/maintainable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you already *have* promises (or at least, deferreds) in your code, so there is no good reason to look for different coding pattern. You can however [*flatten* your callback pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572) by *chaining* the promise callbacks with the allmighty [`then` method](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) instead of nesting them (with `done`):

```
$.wait(1000).then(function() {
//           ^^^^
    //Do something
    return $.wait(5000);
//  ^^^^^^
}).then(function() {
// ^^^^
    //Do something else
    return $.wait(2000);
//  ^^^^^^
}).then(function() {
// ^^^^
    //Do something else
});
```

which is exactly equivalent to your code.