# Call for two method in promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I've the following promise which work well

```
troces.run(value, "../logs/env.txt")
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        return updadeUser(val, arg, args[1])
        // Now here I need to add new method updateAddress(host,port,addr)

    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Now I need to add additional method call inside the the first `.then`
that the update user and the `updateAddress` will work together

My question are

> 1. assume that updateUser will need to start 10 ms after the update
>      address How is it recommended to do so?
> 2. in aspects of error handling if one of the process failed (send error message ) I Need to exit (`process.exit(1);`)

Comment: You can call updateAddress  method from the updateuser method , not from here.

Comment: Why 10ms? That seems a little specific. Are you just waiting for something to start/end?

Comment: You can quite easily create a `timeout` function that takes a duration and returns a promise and chain your other operations using that. I don't know `bluebird` well enough to provide the example, so will leave that to others :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - yes I want something to start for me its fine to do it after100 ms

Comment: But why 10ms? That seems a little specific.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - 100ms is also good

Comment: *sigh*. You are missing my point... why a delay at all? Why not 1ms (or 0 to run the code at the end of the current browser code cycle)?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - ok lets skip the timout how should I call it in parallel I think after the then to call to promise.all but not sure how to write it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.all`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html):

```
troces.run(value, "../logs/env.txt")
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return Promise.all([updadeUser(val, arg, args[1]),
                        updateAddress(host,port,addr)]);
}); // no need to add catches bluebird will log errors automatically
```

If you *really* need the 10ms delay, you can do:

```
troces.run(value, "../logs/env.txt")
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return Promise.all([updadeUser(val, arg, args[1]),
                        Promise.delay(10).then(x => updateAddress(host,port,addr))]);
}); // no need to add catches bluebird will log errors automatically
```

Although I *suspect* that you really just want `updateUser` to happen *before* `updateAddress` which can be easily solved with:

```
troces.run(value, "../logs/env.txt")
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return updadeUser(val, arg, args[1]).then(_ => updateAddress(host,port,addr));
}); // no need to add catches bluebird will log errors automatically
```

If you need to exit on promise error, you can do:

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", () => process.exit(1));
```

Although I warmly recommend you create meaningful error messages, just a non-zero process exit code is hard to debug.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, in this case its better then promise.all?

Comment: @shopiaT no, it is better to use `.all` than `join` in this case, I changed my answer already :)

Comment: Thank you 1+! you are fast :), the problem which I cannot use the last suggestion is I dont know when the update user will be resolved...

Comment: @shopiaT also, I would appreciate it if you told me what wasn't clear in the docs, I've slightly modified them right now. We're looking to improve the docs so - suggestions appreciated. As for  "I don't know when the update user will be resolved" - that's a big problem and you should fix that first. `updateUser` already returns a promise - have that promise resolve when the update finishes.

Comment: HI Benjamin, which docs you refer too? the are many ... bluebird?(i like this lib :) can you please provide a link. about the resolve it can take some time so I dont know actually  when it will be resolved(in some cases it is spawn some process...,why this is a problem?

Comment: Docs are at http://bluebirdjs.com - if you didn't see them then there isn't much I can do about that though. You can still convert APIs like `exec` to use promises and listen for when the process ends.

Comment: Any reason not to flatten the `then`s in the third snippet?

Comment: @Bergi just so it looks visually similar to the other two. Nothing too exciting.

Comment: @Bergi - what do you mean flatting?

Comment: @shopiaT: [flattening the nested callbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572)