# Organize promise code

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, bookshelf.js

I have the following code. But this looks similar to a callback hell. How do i reorganize this code to a more proper promise way

```
   FacilityBooking.forge({
            "booking_id": req.params.id
        })
        .fetch({
            require: true
        })
        .then(function(collection) {
            if(0) { //@todo check if admin
                throw new NotAuthorised(CFG_MESSAGES.error[403]);
            } else {
                Bookshelf.transaction(function(t) {
                    collection
                        .save({
                            "is_valid": 0,
                            "updated_by": req.user.id
                        }, {transacting: t})
                        .tap(function(model) {
                            new FacilityBooking(model.toJSON())
                                 .save({
                                    "is_valid": 1,
                                    "reason_for_reject": req.body.disapprovereason || '' ,
                                    "status": approval_status[req.body.moderation_action]
                                }, {transacting: t})
                                .then(function(collection) {
                                    res.json({
                                        status: true,
                                        message: CFG_MESSAGES.facility_booking.moderate.success
                                    });
                                })
                                .catch(function(err) {
                                    res.json({
                                        status: false,
                                        message: CFG_MESSAGES.facility_booking.moderate.error
                                    });
                                });
                        });
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            ErrorHandler.handleError(res, err);
        });
```

Comment: Why inline everything ?

Comment: Take a look at enrmarc's answer.

Comment: Why use `tap` instead of `then`?

Comment: Doesn't the `transaction` expect your callback to `return` a promise? Does it return a promise itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing nested promises](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572)

Comment: Might be better for code review SE ?

Comment: @aWebDeveloper Can you please Upvote as you have accepted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to answer your question please check below code

```
Bookshelf.transaction(function(t) {
       FacilityBooking.forge({
               "booking_id": req.params.id
           })
           .fetch({
               require: true
           })
           .then(function(collection) {
               if(0) { //@todo check if admin
                   throw new NotAuthorised(CFG_MESSAGES.error[403]);
               } else {
                   return collection
                       .save({
                           "is_valid": 0,
                           'updated_by': req.user.id
                       }, {
                           transaction: t,
                           patch: true
                       });
               }
           })
           .then(function(model) {
               var data = model.toJSON();
               delete data.id;
               return new FacilityBooking(data)
                       .save({
                           "is_valid": 1,
                           "reason_for_reject": req.body.disapprovereason || 'bbbbbbbbbbb' ,
                           "status": approval_status[req.body.moderation_action]
                       }, {
                           transaction: t,
                           method: 'insert'
                       })
           })
           .then(function(collection) {
               res.json({
                   status: true,
                   message: CFG_MESSAGES.facility_booking.moderate.success
               });
           })
           .catch(function(err) {
               res.json({
                   status: false,
                   message: CFG_MESSAGES.facility_booking.moderate.error
               });
           })
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you just can divide it into functions:

```
var onErrorProcessingBooking = function(err) {
  ErrorHandler.handleError(res, err);
};

var tap = function(model) {

  var onSuccessSave = function(collection) {
    res.json({
      status: true,
      message: CFG_MESSAGES.facility_booking.moderate.success
    });
  };

  var onErrorSave = function(err) {
    res.json({
      status: false,
      message: CFG_MESSAGES.facility_booking.moderate.error
    });
  };

  new FacilityBooking(model.toJSON())
    .save({
      "is_valid": 1,
      "reason_for_reject": req.body.disapprovereason || '',
      "status": approval_status[req.body.moderation_action]
      }, {    
      transacting: t
    })
    .then(onSuccessSave)
    .catch(onErrorSave);
}

var onSuccessProcessingBooking = function(collection) {
  if (0) {
     throw new NotAuthorised(CFG_MESSAGES.error[403]);
     return;
  }

  Bookshelf.transaction(function(t) {
    collection
      .save({
       "is_valid": 0,
       "updated_by": req.user.id
       }, {
        transacting: t
      })
      .tap(tap);
  });
}


FacilityBooking
  .forge({"booking_id": req.params.id})
  .fetch({require: true})
  .then(onSuccessProcessBooking)
  .catch(onErrorProcessingBooking);
```

Answer (score 2):

Promises chain, `then` is an abstraction over flow control itself and you can return a promise from another promise. Better yet, you can use coroutines to take care of this with bluebird which is already included in bookshelf:

```
const forger = Promise.coroutine(function*() {
  const collection = yield FacilityBooking.forge({ "booking_id": req.params.id })
                                          .fetch({ require: true });    
  if(0) throw new NotAuthorised(CFG_MESSAGES.error[403]);
  yield Bookshelf.transaction(Promise.coroutine(function *(t) {
    yield collection.save({
      "is_valid": 0,
      "updated_by": req.user.id
    }, {transacting: t});
      const model =  new FacilityBooking(model.toJSON());
      yield model.save({
        "is_valid": 1,
        "reason_for_reject": req.body.disapprovereason || '' ,
        "status": approval_status[req.body.moderation_action]
    }, {transacting: t});
    res.json({
      status: true,
      message: CFG_MESSAGES.facility_booking.moderate.success
    });
  }));
}).catch(function(err) {
  // filter error here, and do the res.json with the failure here
  if(isRelevantError) {
    res.json({
      status: false,
      message: CFG_MESSAGES.facility_booking.moderate.error
    });
  }
  ErrorHandler.handleError(res, err);
});
```

Comment: How does this makes the flow less "callback hell" ? Using a generator doesn't help with this question.

Comment: @elad.chen what do you mean?  OPs code did not handle exceptions correctly and nested for no reason - this code does not suffer from either problem.

Comment: Ignore my comment. Read too quickly.

Comment: no es6 plz. could you plz give me a es5 one. you code a litter bit difficult to follow for me

Comment: Node is built on ES2015, you can use this in Node without any issues don't worry. Also, what part is difficult to follow? Did you read the Promise.coroutine documentation at the bluebird site?

Comment: also why is everything const

Comment: So go read it :) `const` is just a safer `var` for when the reference doesn't change.

Comment: So use a non-deprecated node, although Node 0.12 has generators just fine - you just run it with `node --harmony` and generators are there. Also, this is not a general support forum, if you have more specific questions open new questions.