# Nested Q.all nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm studying the promises with Nodejs.
I've a question about a situation with two nested Q.all.

```
Q.all(promises1)
   .then(function(res1) {
        var promises2 = <METHOD THAT USE THE RES1>
        Q.all(promises2)
            .then(function(re2) {
                  ...
            })
   })
```

The problem is that I need the result of the first Q.all for the second.
The promises1 are multiple save function, and I need the objectId of the item saved in the multiple function that I use in the promises2.
I'am studying the promises for not having nested function, my question is how can I resolve this nest?

Comment: I don't understand the goal.  res1 is in scope here, right?  You can declare these functions at the top level and then just reference them if you're bothered by the nesting.

Comment: Excuse I wasn't clear. I will edit the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> how can I resolve this nest?

[As always](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21999178/1048572) :-) You need to `return` the promise from the `then` callback, in this case the one you got with the second `Q.all` call, and then you can chain your second `then` invocation to the outer promise:

```
Q.all(promises1)
.then(function(res1) {
    var promises2 = … // method that uses `res1`
    return Q.all(promises2)
//  ^^^^^^
}).then(function(res2) {
    …
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a promise from within a then function to continue a chain. Also I want to note that the built in Promise API is supported by node.

```
Promise.all(promises1)
    .then(res => {
        let promises2 = [];
        return Promise.all(promises2);
    })
    .then(res => {

    });
```