# Resolve n from promise and create n promises - how do I do this without nesting promises?

Tags: node.js, callback, promise, chaining

I'm working in node and must make n amount of API calls after getting n returned from a promise. My initial thought would be to create a foreach loop that creates n promises, store them in an array, and then call

`Promise.all(promisesArray).then(function(){...});`

However, this would have the be wrapped in the `then()` call from the original promise, effectively setting up a nested promise situation.

```
getN() //returns a promise object.
.then(function(n) {
    var promisesArray = [];
    for(var i = 0, i < n; i++) {
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { callSomething(i, resolve) });
        promisesArray.push(promise);

    }
    Promises.all(promisesArray).then(function(){
        ... 
        resolve; //resolves original promise
    });
.then(function(something) {...})
.catch(function(err) {...};
```

How can I avoid this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you think is wrong with nesting promises? And why not just [unnest that inner `then` call](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572)?

Comment: Don't forget to `return` the `Promise.all…` from the `then` callback

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, It seemed like most resources I read said that the point of promises is that you don't have to nest anything anymore, so I assumed that it was poor practice to nest like this. Would unnessting the inner `then` call look like: 
`.then(function(n){
    ...
    return Promises.all(promisesArray);
.then(function(values) {...})` ?
So it's technically still nested but just looks cleaner?

Comment: Nesting is fine and [sometimes necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28250687/1048572), the real [point of promises](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) is that you still can `return` even from nested callbacks.

Comment: Yes, `getN().then(function(n) { … return Promise.all(…); }).then(…)` is the correct solution, and it's not even technically any nested `then` calls