# Rejecting Promise if many error sources

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Im in situation where I have many potential error sources. Is there an elegant solution to this mess?

How should I reject it?

```js
  function myFuction(hash) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // this could return error
      const id = atob(hash);

      // this could return error   
      let data = firstFunction(id);

      // return error if not true
      if (data && data.id) {
        // this could return error   
        return secondFunction(data.id)
          .then(item => {

            // return error if not true
            if (item) {
              // this could return error  
              return thirdFunction(item)
                .then(payload => {
                  resolve('OK');
                });
            }
          });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*this could return error*"? Do they throw exceptions?

Comment: `throw new Error('error text');` @Bergi

Comment: Check the edit to my answer

Comment: I think I need to start learning ES6 Promises again, because I have no idea how or why `return Promise.resolve().then(() => { // ...` works. Thanks @Bergi

Comment: It gives us an immediately executed promise `then` callback context where exceptions will be implicitly caught. One could also write `try { atob(…); firstFunction(…) } catch(e) { return Promise.reject(e); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! You can use early returns with `Promise.reject` or just `throw` errors:

```
function myFuction(hash) {
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        // this could throw error
        const id = atob(hash);
        // this could throw error   
        let data = firstFunction(id);

        // return error if not true
        if (!data || !data.id)
            return Promise.reject(new Error("…")); // alternative: throw new Error("…");

        return secondFunction(data.id);
    }).then(item => {
        // return error if not true
        if (!item)
            return Promise.reject(new Error("…")); // same here

        return thirdFunction(item);
    }).then(payload => 'OK');
}
```

(Additionally I applied some [flattening](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572), but as long as your always `return` from promise callbacks you could nest as well)

Comment: Is there a recommendation on `return Promise.reject(new Error(...))` vs. `throw new Error(...)`?  I know they both give you the same outcome, but is there any reason to use one over the other?

Comment: @jfriend00 No idea. `return Promise.reject(…)` works also outside of `then` callbacks, and is a value (can be passed around when it comes handy), while `throw` is shorter and doesn't rely on intact globals. I don't know whether exceptions have a noticeable overhead.