# Same input spammed into promise sometimes passes through when should reject early on

Tags: node.js, promise

```
function createWallet(network, walletToken, deviceToken) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    findWalletByWalletToken(network, walletToken)
    .then((docs) => {
        if (docs.length !== 0) {    
            for (var i in docs) {
                if (docs[i].curDeviceToken == deviceToken || docs[i].walletToken.indexOf(walletToken) !== -1){
                    reject(new Error("walletToken already exists"));
                    return
                }
            }

        }
        console.log(docs)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })

    findDeviceByDeviceToken(network, deviceToken)
    .then((docs) => {
        resolve(docs);
    })
})
.then((docs) => {
          // Adds a wallet
     }
```

The log looks like this

```
Docs in WalletTokenSearch[object Object],[object Object]
Docs in WalletTokenSearch[object Object],[object Object]
Docs in WalletTokenSearch[object Object],[object Object]
Docs in WalletTokenSearch[object Object],[object Object]
Docs in WalletTokenSearch[object Object],[object Object]
Docs in WalletTokenSearch[object Object],[object Object]
Docs in WalletTokenSearch[object Object],[object Object]
[Hail][DB] Inserted new wallet
Docs in WalletTokenSearch[object Object],[object Object]
```

The `Docs in WalletTokenSearch[object Object],[object Object]` is a print statement in `findWalletByWalletToken`

The problem is that I’ll hit the endpoint multiple times and every now and then the same input will pass through the code and get added to the db creating a duplicate… You could do this over and over again and add thousands of duplicates this way

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: do you understand that `findWalletByWalletToken` and `findDeviceByDeviceToken` are essentially running concurrently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always calling both `findWalletByWalletToken` and `findDeviceByDeviceToken`, no matter what. Your promise is fulfilled if the latter finishes first, or when the former doesn't reject the promise. This is a race condition at its finest.

Notice that both actions are executed, regardless of their result. I don't think that's what you want.

```
function createWallet(network, walletToken, deviceToken) {
    return findWalletByWalletToken(network, walletToken).then(docs => {
        for (var i=0; i<docs.length; i++) {
            if (docs[i].curDeviceToken == deviceToken || docs[i].walletToken.indexOf(walletToken) !== -1){
                throw new Error("walletToken already exists");
            }
        }
        console.log(docs)
        // only call this here:
        return findDeviceByDeviceToken(network, deviceToken);
    }).then((docs) => {
        // Adds a wallet
    });
}
```

Comment: So the `docs` var in the .then() will be the output of `findDeviceByDeviceToken`?

Comment: @HarshaGoli Yes, it's because [promises unnest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572).