# is this correct way of using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Here I am first searching for ticket and then train for which ticket is booked.
I am new to promises so I want to know this is the right way or it  can be done without nesting?

```
router.get('/ticket/:id', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    Ticket.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate('passengers')
    .exec()
    .then(foundTicket => {
        Train.findById(foundTicket.trainDetails._id)
        .exec()
        .then(foundTrain => {
            res.render("ticket",{ticket:foundTicket, train:foundTrain});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
});
```

Comment: I don't really see how else you'd do it, other than storing the error callback in a variable, and using that: `const err = e => console.log(e);  /**/ .catch(err);`

Answer (score 0):

Yo can flatten it even further by returning the 2nd promise. Catch will catch any error in the chain.

```
router.get('/ticket/:id', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    Ticket.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate('passengers')
    .exec()
    .then(foundTicket => {
        return Train.findById(foundTicket.trainDetails._id)
        .exec();
    }).then(foundTrain => {
            res.render("ticket",{ticket:foundTicket, train:foundTrain});
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
});
```

Comment: You could shorten it further still by using implicit returns on the `.then` callbacks - e.g. `then(foundTicket => Train.findById(foundTicket.trainDetails._id).exec())`

Comment: Yeah. that's one more thing you can do.

Comment: I am getting error saying "foundTicket is not defined; pleasefix or add /* global found ticket*/"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should [flatten it by `return`ing the inner promise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572) so that you can chain onto it and need only a single error handler.

```
router.get('/ticket/:id', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    Ticket.findById(req.params.id).populate('passengers').exec()
    .then(foundTicket =>
        Train.findById(foundTicket.trainDetails._id).exec()
    ).then(foundTrain => {
        res.render("ticket",{ticket:foundTicket, train:foundTrain});
    }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500); // don't forget to respond!
    });
});
```