# The order of the execution of codes and functions in sails.js and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Please look at the picture below and help me

I want to do something like this:

[image: a busy cat]

I want first part A to be fully executed Then run section B, Because in the first part(A) must the file uploaded compeletly to make the uploaded file name assign to global_d variable, i need this variable in part B.

The next question is how to access a local variable(in this case global_d) from within nested callback functions(in this case part A)?

Please explain me with examples

I hope I have expressed my question carefully.
thank you

Comment: "look at the picture below" — It's a picture of **text**! Why is it a picture and not text?

Comment: I thought that it would be better to express the problem

Comment: It's blurry; it can't be copy/pasted; it's invisible to screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

The callback function is called when the upload is complete.

Put the call to `Book.update` **inside** it.

---

If you want to avoid nesting, the use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and see [Removing Nested Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999178/removing-nested-promises)

Comment: how to access a local variable(in this case global_d) from within nested callback functions(in this case part A)?

Comment: The variable will still be in scope for the nested function. Just use its name.

Comment: But I do the same
But the result is undefined!!

Comment: Then your function is changing it to `undefined`, because you explicitly set its initial value to `null`. Presumably, your real code (represented by the comment "//myuploadedpicname" in the question) is wrong.