# Begin fetch on event, but wait until itself and another promise settles — JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I’m developing an organisational chart. I’m looking for tips on restructuring how I handle two es6-promises for a minor performance gain.

On the click event, I do 3 things sequentially:

1. Play first animation (promise)
2. Fetch all data (promise)
3. Play last animation

Ideally, I would like:

1. Begin fetching data
2. Play first animation
3. Play last animation (requires the fetched data, but can’t play before the first animation has ended)

Here is the code in question:

```
/* Click happened! */

orgWrap.shiftRow({ row: clickY, from: clickX, to: focusX }).then(() => {
    /* Shiftrow is a promise triggering an animation,
       it resolved on 'transitionend' */

    fetch(`api/org/${target.id}/1`).then(result =>  {
        /* a function placing result in the DOM runs
           After data finished loading */

        orgWrap.populateRow({ data: result.children, row: clickY+1 });
        /* The animation which plays last, when shiftRow and fetch has settled */
  });

});
```

As it stands now, there is an occasional unnecessary delay between `shiftRow` and `populateRow` because it fetches all data after the first animation is done and then runs the final animation, instead it should *begin* to fetch data on the initial click. Any tips on how I can refactor and better utilise promises and the power of async? I prefer to keep the functions which are promises to stay promises, the rest I am willing to change. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the fetch and begin animation in a `Promise.all()` and run the end animation after the `Promise.all` resolves.

So:

```js
async function animate() {
  // some animation logic
}

Promise
  .all([
    animate(), // Beginning animation
    fetch("some.html")
  ])
  .then([, neededFetchData] => {
    return animate(neededFetchData);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept this answer because you answered with a code example, but omitted all the irrelevant parts of my code. Thus it may be easier to understand for other people swinging by this thread. +1 bonus points for `[, neededFetchData]`, understanding that the first promise only resolves, but doesn't return any value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Promise.all()` for the first two promises, `then` for the third one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for this:

```
/* Click happened! */

Promise.all([
  orgWrap.shiftRow({ row: clickY, from: clickX, to: focusX }), // Shiftrow is a promise triggering an animation, it resolved on 'transitionend'
  fetch(`api/org/${target.id}/1`),
]).then(([animationResult, fetchResult]) => {
  /* a function placing result in the DOM runs after data finished loading */

  return orgWrap.populateRow({ data: result.children, row: clickY+1 }); // The animation which plays last, when shiftRow and fetch has settled
});
```

Also make sure to [chain your promise callbacks instead of unnecessarily nesting them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572).