# How to reject or stop going further in a chain of AngularJS promises?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, promise, angular-promise

I have two functions which return calls to AngularJS' $http.post.
The two functions are savePart1() & savePart2()

```
savePart1 = (): IPromise<any> => {
    return $http.post(....)
}

savePart2 = (): IPromise<any> => {
    return $http.post(....)
}
```

I am trying to not callPart2() if savePart1() fails. 
I did something like this:

```
this.savePart1().then((response1) => {
    if (response1.status !== 200)
        // don't call savePart2()
        this.savePart2().then((response2) => {
            if(response1.status === 200)
            //display success message when both calls succeed
        }):
}), (error) => {
   //handle error;
}).finally();
```

My question is how to cancel from calling savePart2() if the response from savePart2() did not return status of 200 (not necessarily an error). IPromise doesn't seem to have a reject method. Do I just return from the first promise?

Also my goal is to display a success message when both calls succeed. Is my syntax the best way to do this. I would like to add an error handler when any call fails.

Comment: "*I am trying to not callPart2() if savePart1() did not return status of 200*" - that's exactly what you are doing, nothing wrong with that `if` statement. Or did I misunderstand what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you mostly achieved what you want already. To make the `finally` wait for the second call, you [should `return` the inner promise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) from the `then` callback though.

```
this.savePart1().then(response1 => {
    if (response1.status !== 200)
        return this.savePart2().then(response2 => {
//      ^^^^^^
            if (response1.status === 200)
                … // display success message when both calls succeed
            else
                … // handle non-200 status from call 2
        }, error => {
            … // handle error from call 2
        });
    else
        … // handle non-200 status from call 1
}), error => {
   … // handle error from call 1
}).finally(…);
```

To use a common handler for the errors, you would [switch from `.then(…, …)` to `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572):

```
this.savePart1().then(response1 => {
    if (response1.status !== 200)
        return this.savePart2().then(response2 => {
            if (response1.status === 200)
                … // display success message when both calls succeed
            else
                … // handle non-200 status from call 2
        });
    else
        … // handle non-200 status from call 1
}).catch(error => {
   … // handle errors from both calls
}).finally(…);
```

You could even handle the unexpected status codes there by throwing exceptions:

```
this.savePart1().then(response1 => {
    if (response1.status !== 200)
        throw new Error("unexpected status "+response1.status);
    return this.savePart2().then(response2 => {
        if (response1.status !== 200)
            throw new Error("unexpected status "+response2.status);
        … // display success message when both calls succeed
    });
}).catch(error => {
   … // handle anything
}).finally(…);
```

And if you don't need both response values for displaying the success message, you could then even [unnest the `then` calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572).