# Execute javascript function after previous one finishes

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

I have the function "showElement" that has a setTimeout. How can I make that the calls to the function in the eventListener of the 'btnSend' execute one right after the other one?

I tried with .then() but didn't work.

```
document.getElementById('btnSend').addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    result = validateInputs(email, subject, message);
    if(result) {
        showElement(document.getElementById('formGroupSpinner'), 2000);
        showElement(document.getElementById('formGroupSuccessImg'), 2000);
        resetForm();
    }
});

//expects an html element and a number representing miliseconds. Shows the html element for that amount of time.
function showElement(element, mSeconds) {
    element.classList.remove('d-none');
    element.classList.add('d-block');
    setTimeout( () => {
        element.classList.remove('d-block');
        element.classList.add('d-none');
    }, mSeconds);
}
```

Both functions execute at the same time.

Comment: Hello Floro, you seems new to JS, look for JavaScript callbacks.

Comment: Please add your HTML too :)

Comment: @jo_va not relevant

Comment: To use `then`, you need to [create and return a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many different approaches to this but I would suggest using a Promise like this:

```js
document.getElementById('btnSend').addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var result = validateInputs(email, subject, message);
    if(result){
        showElement(document.getElementById('formGroupSpinner'), 2000).then(()=>{
            return showElement(document.getElementById('formGroupSuccessImg'), 2000);
        }).then(()=>{
            resetForm();
        });
    }
});

//expects an html element and a number representing miliseconds. Shows the html element for that amount of time.
function showElement(element, mSeconds) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        element.classList.remove('d-none');
        element.classList.add('d-block');
        setTimeout( () => {
            element.classList.remove('d-block');
            element.classList.add('d-none');
            resolve();
        }, mSeconds);
    });
}
```

Basically, the function after the `.then()` only gets executed once you called the `resolve();`.

Alternatively you could also use a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) or [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Comment: You'll want to [unnest your `then` calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572), though

Comment: @Bergi I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. If it's important could you maybe please edit the answer?

Comment: Not as important as in "doesn't work", but it's still better style. Edited.

Comment: Thank you, after trying different approaches, this one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a callback to execute other instructions after the function has ended:

```
//First you add a param "callback" to the function
function showElement(element, mSeconds, callback) {
    element.classList.remove('d-none');
    element.classList.add('d-block');
    setTimeout( () => {
        element.classList.remove('d-block');
        element.classList.add('d-none');
        //Then you ask if the callback function is present and call it
        if(callback && typeof callback === "function") callback();
    }, mSeconds);
}

//Then use it in your event like this:
document.getElementById('btnSend').addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    result = validateInputs(email, subject, message);
    if(result) {
        showElement(document.getElementById('formGroupSpinner'), 2000, () => {
            showElement(document.getElementById('formGroupSuccessImg'), 2000);
            resetForm();
        });  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You have to wrap your `showElement()` function into a promise and call the promise resolver once `setTimeout` fires. 
Then your calling code can `pipe` your the promises together with `then`:

```
showElement(document.getElementById('formGroupSpinner'), 2000).then(() => {
    showElement(document.getElementById('formGroupSuccessImg'), 2000).then(() => {
        resetForm();
    });
});
```

However, this quickly leads to callback hell.

You can avoid this by using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).
You mark your function as `async`, then you can use `await` within it to wait for the promises to resolve before continuing to the next one:

```
await showElement(document.getElementById('formGroupSpinner'), 2000);
await showElement(document.getElementById('formGroupSuccessImg'), 2000);
resetForm();
```

Here is a working demo:

```js
document.getElementById('btnSend').addEventListener('click', async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await showElement(document.getElementById('formGroupSpinner'), 2000);
    await showElement(document.getElementById('formGroupSuccessImg'), 2000);
});

function showElement(element, mSeconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    element.classList.remove('d-none');
    element.classList.add('d-block');
    setTimeout(() => {
        element.classList.remove('d-block');
        element.classList.add('d-none');
        resolve();
    }, mSeconds);
  });
}
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnSend">Send</button>

<div id="formGroupSpinner" class="d-none">Spinner</div>
<div id="formGroupSuccessImg" class="d-none">Success image</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, after trying different approaches, this one worked for me. However I ended up using the solution provided by Bergi

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do what you want is simply changing the second **showElement** to **4000** instead of **2000**.

That way one will have a timeout of 2 seconds and the other 4 seconds.

Comment: Yeah that'd work but it would also be very unelegant

Comment: @Sv443 not everything has to be over complicated so it is "elegant"

Comment: Well not only that but it is also more unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

To make a promise chain, you first have to have a promise.

```
function showElement(element, mSeconds) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    element.classList.remove('d-none');
    element.classList.add('d-block');
    setTimeout( () => {
      element.classList.remove('d-block');
      element.classList.add('d-none');
      resolve();
    }, mSeconds);
  }
}
```

Then you can use `showElement().then(/*something here */)`