# Is there a more concise way to resolve or reject Promises that are created in a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, es6-promise

I want to read data from **Firebase Real-Time Database** and **Firebase Storage**. Reading RTDB happens first. This is because the name of the files that are stored in Firebase Storage are the keys of the data in the RDTB. I have the following code:

```
let newReadRef = firebase.database().ref('someRef').limitToLast(3).once('value').then(snapshot => {
  let promiseArray = [];
  snapshot.forEach(e => {
    promiseArray.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      //Do all the things I need to do before trying to get data from my Firebase Storage

      let filePathRef = firebase.storage().ref(e.val().key);
      filePathRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        //Do something with the url
        resolve('Promise resolved');
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        reject('Rejected');
      });
    }));
  });

  Promise.all(promiseArray).then(someFunction);
});
```

The idea is:

1. Retrieve some data from my RTDB, its key will be used later to retrieve data in my Firebase Storage
2. Create a new Promise for each data read in my RTDB
3. For each Promise created, read data from Storage using key obtained from RTDB data. Resolve the Promise when data is read successfully. Otherwise, reject.
4. After all Promises have been created, when all Promise resolves, do something using `someFunction` that will alter the data created

It seems like my code is a little too nested. Is there a better way to achieve the above?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! Also you should [unnest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572) the final `.then(someFunction)`.

Comment: @Bergi By unnesting the final `.then(someFunction)`, do you mean placing the `Promise.all(promiseArray).then(someFunction);` inside a new `then` in my `newReadRef` Promise-returning function?

Comment: @Bergi I don't think I'm using the antipattern you linked?

Comment: I mean you should `return` the `Promise.all(promiseArray)` and then chain `.then(someFunction)` on the outer promise. And yes, you are using the antipattern - Jaromanda's answer shows how to avoid `new Promise` here.

Comment: @Bergi I see. Upon looking again, yes it does have that antipattern on the link you provided (the right code). Thank you for the response :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the code is about as flat as you can get it, though, since the last thing you're doing returns a Promise, you won't need to create a Promise

```
snapshot.forEach(e => {
    //Do all the things I need to do before trying to get data from my Firebase Storage
    let filePathRef = firebase.storage().ref(e.val().key);
    promiseArray.push(
        filePathRef.getDownloadURL()
        .then(url => {
            //Do something with the url
            return 'Promise resolved';
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            throw 'Rejected';
        });
    );
});
```

I was going to suggest using `.map` instead of `.forEach`, but *`snapshot`* isn't a Javascript array if I recall (it has a forEach, but no map method)

Comment: Watch that `catch`, you're turning a rejected promise into a resolved one. Personally, I'd omit the `catch` and let it fall through to the consumer

Comment: Shouldn't I `throw` instead of `return` in my `catch` block?

Comment: Oops, sorry, he did reject in the original, good pickup @Phil

Comment: Also, [`console.error()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/error) because red means stop 

Comment: @Phil - I'll leave that decision to the OP :p