# Why we are not chaining promises inside each other?

Tags: javascript

in one of youtube tutorial videos about promises I found following code:

```
let cleanRoom = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
  });
};

let removeGarbage = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
  });
};

let winIcecream = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
  });
};

cleanRoom().then(function(){
  return removeGarbage();
}).then(function() {
  return winIcecream();
}).then(function() {
  console.log('finished');
})
```

Why the promises aren't chained like that the every .then word is after the previous promise? I mean, why for example `.then` is not immediately after `removeGarbage()` but it is after the `cleanRoom().then()`, how is it happening that the `winIcecream()` will run after resolving the `removeGarbage` promise?
Also do I need to type `return` declaring every promise like in the code above? If yes, why do I need to do so?

Comment: This is a rather bizarre example. Are the async functions supposed to return a value? If so, you might want to create a variable and assign it to the chain of promises. THat way you will have the value

Comment: Actually [we can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572), and [we sometimes do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250687/1048572), we just try to avoid it where we don't need it (as otherwise it leads to a pyramid of doom).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of using a fulfillment handler (the functions passed to `then` in your example) is to wait for the promise to be fulfilled and *then*, at that point, do something else.

The goal of that code (apparently) is to wait until the `cleanRoom` promise is fulfilled, **then** start the `removeGarbage` process, and then when that is fulfilled, start the `winIcecream` process. It's also worth noting that if `cleanRoom`'s promise was *rejected* instead of being fulfilled, `removeGarbage` wouldn't happen at all, because it's in a fulfillment handler, not a rejection handler.

If you did this instead:

```
cleanRoom().then(function() { /*...*/ });
removeGarbage().then(function() { /*...*/ });
winIcecream().then(function() { /*...*/ });
```

...all three processes would be started **immediately** and run in parallel (to the extent whatever async process they're modelling can run in parallel with other JavaScript code). There'd be no coordination between them at all.

> ...how is it happening that the `winIcecream()` will run after resolving the `removeGarbage` promise...

`then`, `catch`, and `finally` create and return *new* promises. Those promises are fulfilled or rejected based on what happens to the promise they were called on and what happens in or is returned by their handler. So for example:

```
doThis()
.then(function() { return doThat(); })
.then(function() { console.log("done"); });
```

Let's call the promise from `doThis()` "Promise A". Calling `then` on it creates a new promise ("Promise B"), that will either be rejected (if Promise A is rejected) or will call its handler if Promise A is fulfilled. Promise B is *resolved to* whatever that handler returns. In the code above, suppose Promise A is fulfilled and `doThat()` returns a promise ("Promise C"). Now, Promise B is resolved to Promise C — whatever happens to Promise C is what will happen to Promise B. If Promise C is fulfilled, Promise B is fulfilled, and the second handler with the `console.log` is called.

The [MDN article on using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) may be helpful.

Comment: Well, no use taking out the garbage until you've cleaned the room to bag up all the trash first?

Comment: @AKX - Exactly.

Comment: @bartekw2213 - FWIW, I cover promises in some detail in Chapter 8 of my new book (see my profile for links).

Answer (score 3):

Your initial questions may be answered by rewriting things to variable assignments.

I'm using arrow function syntax to implicitly `return` the new expression here; if you're using regular functions, then *yes*, you do have to return the new chained promise if you want to run them in sequence.

```js
const roomCleanedPromise = cleanRoom();
const roomCleanedAndGarbageTakenOutPromise = roomCleanedPromise.then(() => removeGarbage());
const roomCleanedAndGarbageTakenOutAndIcecreamWonPromise = roomCleanedAndGarbageTakenOutPromise.then(() => winIcecream());
const finishedPromise = roomCleanedAndGarbageTakenOutAndIcecreamWonPromise.then(() => console.log('finished'));
```

However things are easier written using the more modern `async`/`await` syntax - the YouTube tutorial you mention is a little outdated, perhaps.

```js
async function cleanRoom() {
  console.log('Cleaning room.');
  // this could do other async things or just take a while
  return {room: 'clean'};  // just to demonstrate a return value
}


async function removeGarbage() {
  console.log('Removing garbage.');
  // this could do other async things or just take a while
  return {garbage: 'removed'};
}

// third function elided for brevity

async function doAllTheThings() {
  const roomStatus = await cleanRoom();
  const garbageStatus = await removeGarbage();
  console.log('finished');
}
```

Comment: I like your variable names approach at the top there. It should help people get a better idea what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion / thinking `I mean, why for example .then is not immediately after removeGarbage() but it is after the cleanRoom().then()` is wrong.
Each promise ( .then ) is not execute immediately.

You can take a look at your example ( little edited by me )

```
const cleanRoom = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve();
});

const removeGarbage = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve();
});

const winIcecream = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve();
})

cleanRoom().then(function(){
  console.log('second');
  return removeGarbage();
}).then(function() {
  return winIcecream();
}).then(function() {
  console.log('finished');
})

console.log('first');
```

You should read more how the event loop works.