# Chain Multiply Promises into one chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a sign-in logic with Express and Mongo. I need to put them into one promise chain and avoid nesting promises.

Here is my code:

```
    const foundUser = User.findOne({ email: email }).exec();
    const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    return Promise.all([foundUser, hashedPassword])
        .then(arr => {
            const [ user, hashedPassword ] = arr;

            if (user) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: "This email has already occupied."
                });
            };

            const newUser = new User({
                fullName,
                email,
                password: hashedPassword
            });

            newUser.save()
            .then(user => {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: `${user.fullName}, you are successfully registered.`
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(500);
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500);
        });
```

I tried to use to combine them with `Promise.all`, but one of my promises depends on the previous one, so I added `newUser.save()` in my then.

I achieved that async/awaits like this:

```
const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email: email }).exec();

if (foundUser) {
    return res.status(400).json({
        message: "This email has already occupied."
    });
}

const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

const newUser = new User({
    fullName,
    email,
    password: hashedPassword
});

const user = await newUser.save();

return res.status(200).json({
    message: `${user.fullName}, you are successfully registered.`
});

} catch (err) {
    console.log( err);
    return res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Error'
    })
}
```

But I wonder is there a way to do it with promises and without nesting.
I need to put them on one chain so I can avoid using multiply catches

Comment: Why don't you use async/await instead?

Comment: @cadenzah yeah I know about that, but I want to achieve that with promises instead.

Comment: @RobertHovhannisyan `async`/`await` *is* promises, just a nicer syntax than `then`

Comment: If you just want to avoid multiple catches, that [doesn't mean you have to avoid nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bergi mentioned in the comment, you can return a promise from your `.then` callback. Depending on if this returned promise gets resolved or rejected, your `.then` or `.catch` next in the chain is called. You can do something like this:

```js
    const foundUser = User.findOne({ email: email }).exec();
    const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    return Promise.all([foundUser, hashedPassword])
        .then(arr => {
            const [ user, hashedPassword ] = arr;

            if (user) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: "This email has already occupied."
                });
            };

            const newUser = new User({
                fullName,
                email,
                password: hashedPassword
            });

            return newUser.save()
        })
        .then(user => {
            return res.status(200).json({
                message: `${user.fullName}, you are successfully registered.`
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500);
        });
```