# Breaking the promise chain

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Considering all `job1, job2, job3 and job4` return promises, what is the difference between apart from nuances of code readability. What does test() return in either case? Let's say doSomething() is a heavy async operation, should chaining be used or first method be used?

```
function test() {
    return job().then(function() {
        return job2().then(function() {
            return job3().then(function() {
                return job4().then(function() {
                    doSomething();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

and

```
function test() {
    return job()

    .then(function() {
        return job2();
    })

    .then(function() {
        return job3();
    })

    .then(function() {
        return job4();
    })

    .then(function() {
        doSomething();
    });
}
```

Comment: The last `then` is not returning anything... So in both cases, I guess `test()` returns `undefined`. Could you post some code that is more *complete* than *minimal* ?

Comment: "*Let's say doSomething() is a heavy async operation*" - then why does it not return a promise like the `jobN` functions do?

Comment: [They're equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572)

Comment: The question does not reflect what is normally understood by [breaking a promise chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250704/3478010).

Comment: One of the benefits we get from the Promise interface is that it resolves "callback hell". You can still visit that hell *with* promises... but why should you?

Answer (score 2):

In each method the jobs will be run in the same order, and the function `test` will return a promise that resolves with `undefined` (however, if your code is meant to `return doSomething()`, then `test` will return a promise with the value from `doSomething` in both cases). And as far as I can see, there is no significant performance different between the 2. Either solution seems optimal, and it would just be a question of preference.

The same result is also created by using the `async/await` keywords.

```js
async function test() {
  await job()
  await job2()
  await job3()
  await job4()
  await doSomething()
  // or `return await doSomething()` if you are suppose to return the value
}
```

Comment: The only difference would be the scope of the `then` callback parameters (for job results, e.g. passing them to `doSomething`) if there were any.

Comment: You meant both functions return a fullfilled promise with undefined as promiseResult right?

Comment: Ah yes, that's right. I'll update my answer. good catch