# How can I convert this async function to promise?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Hello I have this async function which retrieves user profile and repositories through github api and returns them in an object.

And I want to convert this to a promise based function by using promise chaining (without any helper methods).

```
async function getUser(user) {
  const profileResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`);
  const profileData = await profileResponse.json();

  const repoResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}/repos`);
  const reposData = await repoResponse.json();
  // returning an object with profile and data
  return {
    profile:profileData,
    repos:repoData,
  };
}

//Calling the function here.
getUser("abufattah").then((res) => console.log(res));
```

I have managed to get it done using two helper functions and promise.all() method.

But how can I achieve the same thing by using promise chaining without any helper functions.

```
//Helper function 1: returns a promise with user profile data.
function getUserProfile(user) {
  return fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
         .then((res) =>res.json());
}


//Helper function 2: returns a promise with user repositories data.
function getUserRepos(user) {
  return fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}/repos?per_page=5&sort=created`)
         .then((res) => res.json());
}
//Main function
function getUserWithPromise(user) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let profile = getUserProfile(user);
    let repos = getUserRepos(user);

    Promise.all([profile, repos]).then((values) => {
      resolve({ profile: values[0], repos: values[1] });
    });
  });
}

// calling the function here
getUserWithPromise("abufattah").then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Regardless of how (or whether) you do it, you'll want to handle checking `ok` on `response`; right now, that code is falling prey to the `fetch` API footgun I describe [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: Your code using `Promise.all` doesn't do what your original function does, it handles the requests **in parallel**, but your original handled them **in series**. Is that intentional?

Comment: Why tho…?! The explicit `new Promise` is most certainly entirely unnecessary. What problem does "using promises instead of `await`" solve for you?

Comment: "*I want to convert this to a promise based function*" - your function **is** promise-based already, and it does return a promise, regardless whether you use `.then()` or `await` syntax.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no that wasnt intentional :p

Comment: @deceze i was just curious how it works under the hood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transformation of `async`/`await` syntax to `.then()` calls is quite mechanical, especially if it doesn't involve any control flow syntax (loops or conditionals):

```
function getUser(user) {
  return fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`).then(profileResponse => {
    return profileResponse.json().then(profileData => {
      return fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}/repos`).then(repoResponse => {
        return repoResponse.json().then(reposData => {
          // returning an object with profile and data
          return {
            profile:profileData,
            repos:reposData,
          };
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

But there's no good reason to write code like that. If it's just that your target environment does not support `async`/`await`, let a transpiler do the transformation.

Comment: Prego, so much better than that pesky `await`… *Not.*

Comment: @Bergi You call yourself ES6 and `Promise` evangelist, and still manage to write such an ugly and crappy code?! Your code has little to do with ES6 and it uses Promises in a very bad way. Check my answer to see how it is done correctly. Sooo much better than that pesky `await`.

Comment: @ElinY. I didn't write that code. I ran a mechanical transformation on the OP's code, to demonstrate *how to convert*. Yes it's ugly, and my answer explicitly recommends not to use this. Still, it is *correct* code, not bad usage of promises, and could then [be flattened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572) without changing behaviour. But again, there is no reason to do that, you should just write simple and straightforward `async`/`await` code! If your target environment doesn't support it, let a transpiler do the work.

Answer (score 3):

You can:

```
//Main function
function getUserWithPromise(user) {
  return Promise.all([
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`).then((res) =>res.json()),
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}/repos?per_page=5&sort=created`).then((res) => res.json())
  ]).then(([result1, result2]) => ({ profile: result1, repos: result2 }));
}

// calling the function here
getUserWithPromise("abufattah").then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Chain:

```
function getUserWithPromise(user) {
  return fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
    .then((res) => {
      return fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}/repos?per_page=5&sort=created`).then((fetch2Result) => ([res.json(), fetch2Result.json()]))
    }).then(([result1, result2]) => ({ profile: result1, repos: result2 }))
}

// calling the function here
getUserWithPromise("abufattah").then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [babel-plugin-transform-async-to-promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-async-to-promises), it seems to have 400,135 downloads per week, but you should use it carefully as it is not maintained for several years, before you use it, perhaps you should have a look at its issues first.

Answer (score -1):

Simple:

```js
const getUser = user => Promise
  .all([
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`).then(res => res.json()),
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}/repos`).then(res => res.json()),
  ])
  .then(([profile, repos]) => ({profile, repos}));
```

That async/await is the most crappiest anti-pattern added to the JS. Don't use them, instead learn how to use promises correctly.

Comment: This does not work. `profileData` is unavailable in the last `then` callback.

Comment: @Bergi sorry, updated my code using Promise.all() for parallel requests. Now looks much better.