# How to wait for multiple async calls to finish in a `then` before the next `then`?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I make a async call to get some data. Then, I need to make 3 async calls. After those 3 calls finish I want to do something else. I've tried this:

```
let outerApi;

getApi(url).then(function(api) {
  outerApi= api;
  return doSomething(api, "cars");
}).then((cars) => {
   //3 async calls
   call1(outerApi, cars);                 
   call2(outerApi, cars);             
   call3(outerApi, cars);
}).then(call1ReturnValue, call2ReturnValue, call3ReturnValue => {
   doSomething(call1ReturnValue, call2ReturnValue, call3ReturnValue);
});
```

The value pass to doSomething are all undefined. How can I wait for the 3 async calls to complete? I know how to do this as the first step of chain via `Promise.all` but not sure how this is accomplished in a `then`.

**Update**

Thanks all for the feedback. Here's what I tried:

Replacing `then` with `Promise.all` as suggested by @ControlAltDel:

```
let outerApi;

getApi(url).then(function(api) {
  outerApi= api;
  return doSomething(api, "cars");
}).Promise.all([
   //3 async calls
   call1(outerApi, cars),                 
   call2(outerApi, cars),             
   call3(outerApi, cars)])
).then(call1ReturnValue, call2ReturnValue, call3ReturnValue => {
   doSomething(call1ReturnValue, call2ReturnValue, call3ReturnValue);
});
```

The results in an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'all')`

As suggested by @DannyMoshe, return `Promise` in first `then`:

```
let outerApi;

getApi(url).then(function(api) {
  outerApi= api;
  return doSomething(api, "cars");
}).then((car) => {
   return Promise.all([
   //3 async calls
   call1(outerApi, cars),                 
   call2(outerApi, cars),             
   call3(outerApi, cars)]);
).then(call1ReturnValue, call2ReturnValue, call3ReturnValue => {
   doSomething(call1ReturnValue, call2ReturnValue, call3ReturnValue);
});
```

`call2ReturnValue` & `call3ReturnValue` are undefined when calling `doSomething`.

**My solution**

```
let outerApi;

getApi(url).then(function(api) {
  outerApi= api;
  return doSomething(api, "cars");
}).then((car) => {
   return Promise.all([
   //3 async calls
   call1(outerApi, cars),                 
   call2(outerApi, cars),             
   call3(outerApi, cars)]);
).then(([call1ReturnValue, call2ReturnValue, call3ReturnValue]) => {
   doSomething(call1ReturnValue, call2ReturnValue, call3ReturnValue);
});
```

From [Promise.all documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), the fulfulliment values are an array of fulfillment values. My previous attempt was not expecting an array.

Comment: See Promise.all(...)

Comment: "*not sure how this is accomplished in a `then`.*" - in exactly the same way. `Promise.all` returns a promise, and you can use that in promise chaining like any other (like you already did with `return doSomething(…)`, for example)

Comment: @ControlAltDel - Thanks for the link. I'm aware of `Promise.all` but how could I use that in a `then`. I would prefer not to have a nested `then`.

Comment: Just declare the promises: `call1Promise = call1(outerApi, cars); call2Promise = call2(outerApi, cars); call3Promise = call3(outerApi, cars);` and return `Promise.all([call1Promise, call2Promise, call3Promise])` in the first then

Comment: @James [You don't have to nest the `.then()` calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572) (although [there is nothing wrong with nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250687/1048572) either)

Comment: @ControlAltDel - Thanks for the help. I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'all')` when replacing `then` with `Promise.all`

Comment: @James I'd suggest looking at the documentation for `Promise.all` rather than just assuming you can paste it in place of `.then` as you have.

Comment: @KevinB - Thanks for your comment. Thanks to all the feedback and looking at the documentation, I see that Promise.all fulfillment value is an array of fulfillment values, in the order of the promises passed. I'll update my OP with my solution using the much appreciated help of everyone here.

Comment: @ControlAltDel, Bergi, thanks to both of you. I'm new to this part of JS. So thanks for bearing with me.